# Retrieving data from HashSet object of type List<string>

Tags: asp.net, c#-4.0

I've created a HashSet object:

```
HashSet<List<string>> objHS = new HashSet<List<string>>();
```

and then I'm dynamically creating multiple lists i.e `(List<string> lst = new List<string>())`.

I'm able to add these lists in objHS i.e `(objHS.Add(lst))`. Now, since there are multiple 
lists, each of these will be having an index no. in objHS. I've used for loop so, that i can keep track of lists. Here's what I'm facing the problem, I'm not able to retrieve the values of these lists from objHS.

Code:-

```
            for (int intlstcols = 0; intlstcols < intCols; intlstcols++)
        {
            List<string> lstCommon = new List<string>();
            for (int intlstrows = 0; intlstrows < intRows; intlstrows++)
            {
                lstCommon.Add(sheetEntries[intlstrows, intlstcols]);
            }
            objHS.Add(lstCommon);
        }
```

Comment: If you post the code snippet it will useful for people to help you better.

Answer (score 0):

if you are able to add the lists in objHS then Go to the Debug Mode and get the QuickWatch and go through the expressions, surely you will be able to find how to retrive the values.